# NoSuchMethodError in SQL Developer when using the OCI driver

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to set up SQL Developer to use the OCI driver.  I downloaded the Instant Client, and configured it liked this

[image]

When I click the Test button, it appears to be successful

```
Testing the Instant Client located at C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
  Driver version: 21.11.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... OK
Success!
```

But when I run a query, I got this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.clearConnStrategyStack()V
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.handleAcceptPacket(NSProtocolNIO.java:784)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.handleConnectPacketResponse(NSProtocolNIO.java:375)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:216)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:354)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:2653)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:669)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1094)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:90)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:732)
    at oracle.jdbc.datasource.impl.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:689)
    at oracle.jdbc.datasource.impl.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:380)
    at oracle.jdbc.datasource.impl.OracleDataSource.getConnectionInternal(OracleDataSource.java:2153)
    at oracle.jdbc.datasource.impl.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:353)
    at oracle.jdbc.datasource.impl.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:314)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.createConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:428)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnectionImpl(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:400)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:120)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt$DefaultPrompter.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:154)
    at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.PasswordPrompter.promptForPassword(PasswordPrompter.java:15)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:202)
    at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:391)
    at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:374)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CAConnectionCreator.createConnectionImpl(CAConnectionCreator.java:52)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:838)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:282)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:656)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:285)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1181)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1167)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet$WorksheetController.testConnection(Worksheet.java:681)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet$WorksheetController$1.doWork(Worksheet.java:629)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: which version of Oracle Database, and we need to know about your query, and the type of data being returned from said query .. assuming SELECT 1 FROM DUAL works?

Comment: I'm using 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0.  I get that same error when running any query, including running SELECT 1 FROM DUAL.

Comment: let's go the other way around then, why do you think you need an OCI THICK connection vs just a basic JDBC connection? Also, 11204 is on it's very very last legs in terms of support

Comment: When I cancel a running query, it takes a long time to cancel.  According to the Internet - [your page actually](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/04/die-or-how-to-cancel-queries-in-oracle-sql-developer/) - switching to the OCI client should fix that.

Comment: It helps, yes. Might be easier to just have sqlcl session ready as needed to kill sessions. You may just need an older version of SQL Dev since your DB is so old, the newer drivers/clients are advanced 10, 15+ years since 11g.